# Persisted thread pool in c# web environment

Tags: c#, threadpool

I wrote a c# datacentric web application.
This application needs to perform some things asynchronously (for example, sending email, transmitting some data to external api), but I want them to be persisted for any case of crash / restart.
I also want to pass some data that will be persisted, so when the thread wakes up, it will have this data for the invocation. when I say data, I mean data context, some structured object, so when the thread wakesup, it will have the data for the thread operation, incase of email, To,subject and body.

So just to visualized it, here is an api that I can think of...

```
public interface IAsyncService{
   void QueueWork<T>(object dataContext) where T : IAsyncOperation;
}

public interface IAsyncOperation{
    void ExecuteQueuedWork(object dataContext);
}
```

Does this case scenario possible in .net native? if not, do you know any other possible solution for that?

Comment: Is it possible to persist data in .NET? Yes, of course it is. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Your question is too broad in it's current form. What are the "some things" which need to be asynchronous? How should they "be persisted"? What is the "some data" are you passing and where are you passing it to? What is the "invocation"? How will the the "thread wakes up"? #

Comment: @DanPuzey, if you dont have any helpful information to bring to the table, please stay away.

Comment: @AviFatal I found Dan's information very helpful.

Comment: @AviFatal: I'll have helpful information to bring when the question is specific; right now the question *can* be paraphrased as "is it possible to persist data in .NET?" - hence my comment. This site generally expects clear, concise questions, not a vague description of a problem. Data can be persisted in half a dozen different ways, for starters, which already makes this question too broad for this forum even *without* considering the over-vague threading aspect that's mentioned.

Comment: @AviFatal: I agree with Dan. I was just in chatty mood, so I provided some generic answer about the problem, but most likely OP has something more in mind that the general bits I wrote..

Comment: I can agree with Avi... nevertheless, I have added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no.

You can't "persist a thread". That's simply impossible. Thread is a low-level thing.

However, you can have the expected result. Just persist the **jobs**, not threads. Job (or task, or workitem, or whatever you would like to name it) is the set of input data that defines the task to be performed, plus, optionally, the information about progress, temporary results, and similar things.

If you define the "job" just as a set of input data, you will be able to have a pool of workers that will start processing the jobs. When a worker crashes, assuming the job is still persisted, you will be able to start a new worker and let it process the failed job **again from the beginning**.

If you inclide in the "job" some temporary (partial) results, then after a crash, your new worker can start its work from that saved point.

Now, the granularity of savepoints (if any), the tracking of "which thread does what job", the tracking "what job is completed and which are not" - are solely your responibilities. You have to design and write all of that yourself. That's doable, not that hard, but requires a bit of planning.

Or, with a bit of luck, you might find workerpool/messagequeueing/etc library. I don't remember any right now.

Comment: +1 for somehow having extracted meaning from the above question

Comment: I up-voted simply for your question interpretation skills. :)

Comment: I would have limited my answer to the first line. "Yes and no."

Comment: Thank you, I understand that thread is not persistable, but I wanted to find some queue that will be able to run the jobs inside my process and not in a different. I know it is doable, but still Im lookin for public library with mature stability. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF: See the [**HangFire**](http://hangfire.io/), maybe? We are using it currently but for a bit different problem. I dont know how much "persistable" it is without any additions, but we have few workers working, no "windows service" needed, so it's probably a very good start for having extra workers in a web app.. sorry, I simply don't know what to add more.

Comment: @SexyMF: Btw. if you are asking for a library, then your question falls into "offtopic/request for an offsite resource like a tool or library".. sorry, still going to be closed.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - it is exactlly what i wanted, inproccess thread management. and it is persisted!!! thank you!